# AppBarLayout traps keyboard focus

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm trying to ensure that keyboard navigation works properly on my app and all view elements are focusable when users hit the 'Tab' key or 'Up/Down' arrow keys. However, the AppBarLayout seems to trap keyboard focus. I'm running my app on an emulator with a keyboard configured. A sample layout is as below:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_fragment_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/recycler_view">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Sample text 1"
                android:focusable="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Sample text 2"
                android:focusable="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@layout/content_main"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hitting the Tab key or the Up/Down arrows does not switch the focus over to the recycler view and the focus is stuck within the AppBarLayout. Setting the nextFocusDown attribute on the textviews and setting the view elements to remain focusable does not work either. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yToqx.png) is the image. What do I need to do to make this layout accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to release keyboard focus from AppBarLayout is to hook an actual device (NOT the emulator) to a keyboard and hit the keys Cmd+Tab (for Mac OS users) or Windows+Tab (for Windows users).

Comment: Here is some documentation. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0#kbnc

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to call

```
    findViewById(R.id.search_fragment_app_bar).setTouchscreenBlocksFocus(false);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        findViewById(R.id.search_fragment_app_bar).setKeyboardNavigationCluster(false);
    }
```

[setTouchscreenBlocksFocus](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#setTouchscreenBlocksFocus(boolean))

[setKeyboardNavigationCluster](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setKeyboardNavigationCluster(boolean))

Comment: setTouchscreenBlocksFocus works like a charm, thank you! 

Is there any idea why it works like that? From documentation: 
"Set whether this ViewGroup should ignore focus requests for itself and its children. If this option is enabled and the ViewGroup or a descendant currently has focus, focus will proceed forward." But in our case we don't need to ignore focus, vice versa!

Comment: Perfect solution! This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @whereismaxmax When we click on keyboard Tab or arrow buttons, ViewGroup will receive a focus change request and will call [focusSearch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#focusSearch(android.view.View,%20int)) method to find next focus view. I think if TouchscreenBlocksFocus flag is true, the AppBarLayout will be treated as an "effective root" and it will ignore request to move focus to outside views.